# RxJS5: how to map and filter on one go - like 'collect' in Scala?

Tags: rxjs5

In my Scala coding, I have found the `collect` method pretty useful. It allows one to both filter and transform items, on one go.

There does not seem to be anything such in RxJS. Have I missed something obvious, or is it considered unnecessary?

The helper I did is trivial:

https://github.com/akauppi/svg.rx.js/blob/master/src/svg.rx.js#L27-L42

Answer (score 2):

There isn't a way other than `.filter(someFn).map(otherFn)`. It could be added, I supposed (I'm a contributor)... but the benefits would be minimal. They already basically act as transducers and are extremely performant. If you do something like: `Observable.from([1,2,3,4]).filter(x => x % 2).map(x => x + '!!!')` it's only going to roll through the array one time. Which is unlike Array.filter.map, where you're going through it (maybe) twice.

I hope that answers your question. If you think it should be a feature, [come propose an issue](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJS/issues) and the community can discuss it, but my gut tells me it's probably not a necessary optimization.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I merely wanted to make sure I hadn't missed something.